# how to get facebook posts pagination in wordpress

Tags: facebook, pagination

I am getting Facebook posts in WordPress using `file_get_contents()`:

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$page_name/posts?fields=full_picture,picture,name,description,story,id,source,link,message,permalink_url,attachments,type&limit=$limit&access_token=$access_token");

$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

How to get posts pagination without using Facebook SDK?

Comment: prev/next URLs or cursor values should be part of the returned data.

Comment: well. thank you. i am researching but unable to found how to give cursor value.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Comment: how to get before and after value?

Comment: Again: Those are part of the data structure you got returned from your first request.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? The response the API gives does not change based on what particular function you used to make the request.

Comment: Thank you for your help. got before and after code but i am worrying on its implementation.

Comment: Well you have to add those parameters to your original request URL. Or you use the `prev`/`next` URLs that you should also find in the API response - those are already “prepared” to include those additional parameters, so that you can use those URLs directly to request the next posts in those directions.

Comment: Its now fixed. thanks for your support.